# MS Access 1-to-many database from Excel multivalued field

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, relationship

VBA for MS Access - Multiple columns of rows with multivalued line feeds of data to separate.

I have an Excel spreadsheet (given to me) with the following fields: `ID` [number], `FullName` [txt], `Grade` [number], `LocationCriteria` [txt - multivalued field separated by line feeds].

I need to produce a report [in Access] that groups Applicants by Location with the names of the applicants underneath with their grades from highest to lowest.

ie City Name, then below would be the names of the applicants who picked Vancouver..Joe, Mary Sue etc in order of who has the highest grade. The applicant can choose up to eight locations where they would like to work. All of the locations are in one Excel field separated by line breaks.

What is the best way to separate the LocationCriteria field into their own rows or records into another table and match the ID # of the applicant so I have a one to many setup?

I would then have two tables: PARENT TABLE: tblApplicantInfo [`ID`, `FullName`, `Grade`] and CHILD TABLE: `LocationID`, `ID` (Foreign key), `Location`.  One applicant could be in several groups and situated differently in order depending on their grade.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I created a 1-M join but I now realize that I have a many-to-many relationship so that's good. But I still don't know how to link the applicants table to  other tables so I have the Prim Key and Foreign Key values aligning. Do I have to type the foreign keys in myself to have the records link up?  I have several values in one excel field that need to be broken apart and assigned the PK which will become the FK when moved to other tables.

Answer (score 0):

If understand your requirement correctly, I would create 3 tables:

### Applicants

Id
Full name
Grade

### Locations

Id
Location

### ApplicantsToLocations

Id 
Applicant_Id (foreign key)
Location_Id (foreign key)

You would then need to populate the Locations table with unique only locations from the spreadsheet, then populate the Applicants table, and finally ApplicantsToLocations

Comment: If I separate the data from one excel document into separate tables, how do I automatically create joins based the Primary Key in the Applicants table to he other tables? How do I add ie. the PK 1 for Sue Smith to the FK in the Locations table so I create a link. There could be 5  - one's of foreign key due to five location choices? I won't be entering data only separating it and creating a report.

Comment: I need to somehow a) take out the mutivalued rows of data in one excel field LocationCriteria and have those child records  moved to the Locations table and link up the the Applicants table where they came?  Make Sense?

Answer (score 0):

```
            Option Compare Database
            Option Explicit
            Option Base 1
            Dim strInputString As String
            Dim intNumberOfArrayEntries As Integer
            Dim strStateArray(6) As String

            ' ***********************************************************************
            ' Loop Through A Table With A Multi-Value Field
            ' And Insert Values Into the Multi-Value Field From A
            ' Parsed Regular Text Field
            '
            ' Original code acquired from:
            ' http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/384f46cd-2a67-4efa-883e-83004700e144/how-to-import-into-a-table-with-multivalue-fields?forum=accessdev
            '
            ' This code will take data from a string field, parse it into an array
            ' for the multi-valued field, and append it to any existing data in the
            ' multi-valued field of the same record.
            '
            ' This code uses a single recordset to process data, therefore, if you
            ' wish to use this code, both your string field and your multi-value
            ' field must be in the same table. (Perhaps import a temporary field?)
            '
            ' If you wish to incorporate this into your database, note the following
            ' changes you should make to the code prior to using it:
            '   TABLENAME is the table you will be using and holds both your string
            '       which will be converted and your multi-valued field and the
            '       multi-valued field
            '       There are 13 instances of TABLENAME in this code (+ 2 for here/above)
            '   MULTIVALUEFIELD is the field which holds your multi-valued field and
            '       after using this code, the items converted to the multi-value
            '       type will be appended to the items, if any, that are currently
            '       stored in the given record.
            '       There are 13 instances of MULTIVALUEFIELD in this code (+ 2 for here/above)
            '   STRINGFIELD is the field which holds a string of the combined,
            '       comma-separated values. This field will be broken up into
            '       individual entries for use in the multi-value field
            '       There is 1 instances of STRINGFIELD in this code (+ 2 for here/above)
            '   If you use "Find and Replace function" replace each of the above names
            '   exactly with your appropriate database names and watch for the count
            '   of changes that it matches the "# of instances" for each
            '
            ' ***********************************************************************


            ' Call this function name to start action
            Public Function InsertIntoMultiField()

            Dim db As DAO.Database

            ' ***********************************************************************
            ' Main recordset containing both a multi-value field and string field
            ' ***********************************************************************
            Dim TABLENAME As DAO.Recordset2
            ' ***********************************************************************
            ' Now Define the Multi-Value Fields as a RecordSet
            ' ***********************************************************************
            Dim rsMULTIVALUEFIELD As DAO.Recordset2

            ' ***********************************************************************
            ' The Values of the Field Are Contained in a Field Object
            ' Dim fldMULTIVALUEFIELDTemp As DAO.Field2
            ' ***********************************************************************
            Dim fldMULTIVALUEFIELD As DAO.Field2
            Dim i As Integer

            ' ***********************************************************************
            ' Open the Parent File
            ' ***********************************************************************
            Set db = CurrentDb()
            Set TABLENAME = db.OpenRecordset("TABLENAME")

            ' ***********************************************************************
            ' Set The Multi-Value Field
            ' ***********************************************************************
            Set fldMULTIVALUEFIELD = TABLENAME("Applications")

            ' ***********************************************************************
            ' Check to Make Sure it is Multi-Value
            ' ***********************************************************************
            If Not (fldMULTIVALUEFIELD.IsComplex) Then
                MsgBox ("Not A Multi-Value Field")
                TABLENAME.Close
                Set TABLENAME = Nothing
                Set fldMULTIVALUEFIELD = Nothing
                Exit Function
            Else
                'MsgBox ("Selected field IS a multi-value field")
            End If

            On Error Resume Next
            ' ***********************************************************************
            ' Loop Through
            ' ***********************************************************************
            Do While Not TABLENAME.EOF

            ' ***********************************************************************
            ' Parse Regular Text Field into Array For Insertion into Multi-Value
            ' ***********************************************************************
                strInputString = TABLENAME!STRINGFIELD
                Call ParseInputString

            ' ***********************************************************************
            ' If Entries Are Present, Add Them To The Multi-Value Field
            ' ***********************************************************************
                If intNumberOfArrayEntries > 0 Then
                    Set rsMULTIVALUEFIELD = fldMULTIVALUEFIELD.Value
                    TABLENAME.Edit
                    For i = 1 To intNumberOfArrayEntries
                        rsMULTIVALUEFIELD.AddNew
                        rsMULTIVALUEFIELD("Value") = strStateArray(i)
                        rsMULTIVALUEFIELD.Update
                    Next i
                    rsMULTIVALUEFIELD.Close
                    TABLENAME.Update
                End If
            TABLENAME.MoveNext
            Loop

            On Error GoTo 0

            TABLENAME.Close
            Set TABLENAME = Nothing
            Set rsMULTIVALUEFIELD = Nothing
            End Function

            Public Function ParseInputString()
            Dim intLength As Integer
            Dim intStartSearch As Integer
            Dim intNextComma As Integer
            Dim intStartOfItem As Integer
            Dim intLengthOfItem As Integer
            Dim strComma As String

            strComma = ","
            intNumberOfArrayEntries = 0
            strInputString = Trim(strInputString)
            intLength = Len(strInputString)

            ' ***********************************************************************
            ' Skip Zero Length Strings
            ' ***********************************************************************
            If intLength = 0 Then
                Exit Function
            End If

            ' ***********************************************************************
            ' Strip Any Leading Comma
            ' ***********************************************************************
            If Mid(strInputString, 1, 1) = "," Then
                Mid(strInputString, 1, 1) = " "
                strInputString = Trim(strInputString)
                intLength = Len(strInputString)
                If intLength = 0 Then
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If

            ' ***********************************************************************
            ' Strip Any Trailing Comma
            ' ***********************************************************************
            If Mid(strInputString, intLength, 1) = "," Then
                Mid(strInputString, intLength, 1) = " "
                strInputString = Trim(strInputString)
                intLength = Len(strInputString)
                If intLength = 0 Then
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If

            intStartSearch = 1
            ' ***********************************************************************
            ' Loop Through And Parse All the Items
            ' ***********************************************************************
            Do
                intNextComma = InStr(intStartSearch, strInputString, strComma)
                If intNextComma <> 0 Then
                    intNumberOfArrayEntries = intNumberOfArrayEntries + 1
                    intStartOfItem = intStartSearch
                    intLengthOfItem = intNextComma - intStartOfItem
                    strStateArray(intNumberOfArrayEntries) = Trim(Mid(strInputString, intStartOfItem, intLengthOfItem))
                    intStartSearch = intNextComma + 1
                Else
                    intNumberOfArrayEntries = intNumberOfArrayEntries + 1
                    intStartOfItem = intStartSearch
                    intLengthOfItem = intLength - intStartSearch + 1
                    strStateArray(intNumberOfArrayEntries) = Trim(Mid(strInputString, intStartOfItem, intLengthOfItem))
                End If

            Loop Until intNextComma = 0

            End Function


            ' ***********************************************************************
            ' Original code credit to: Rich Locus, Logicwurks, LLC
            ' From: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/384f46cd-2a67-4efa-883e-83004700e144/how-to-import-into-a-table-with-multivalue-fields?forum=accessdev
            ' Accessed: 23 September 2014
            ' Edited by: ghost0245 (user - social.msdn.microsoft.com)
            ' ***********************************************************************
```